# Any experiences migrating from MDaemon to MS Exchange Online?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, mdaemon, exchangeonline

I will probably be moving from MDaemon to Exchange Online shortly - MDaemon's interface to Outlook is just too slow for remote users. Does anyone have any experiences with the migration that they would care to share?

I have 100 users on MDaemon, some with >4Gb mailboxes, most of them are using IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

I had to migrate one from MDaemon to Exchange 2007,because they had 20 users only, so we just exported each mailbox to a PST.

Setup AD / Exchange and imported PSTs.
How many mailboxes do you have on MDaemon ?

Answer (score 0):

Did that in 2013. It was a Royal Pain, because IMAP migration just didn't work and we had to export everyting to PST files. See [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/534819/how-to-share-a-smtp-domain-between-mdaemon-and-exchange) for some tips about mail routing, which was *also* a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Migrate to local Exchange on-prem, AD setup will be required, if not exists today.
Exchange Hybrid and subsequent complete "Cloud only" deployment follows.